# regarding time cost in recursion

Tags: recursion, runtime, iteration

If a program can be written both by recursion as well as iteration and if we have to decide one of the way, only on the basis of lesser wastage of time,then which method will be faster-recursion or iteration?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Implementation of an algorithm doesn't get more or less efficient because of recursive or iterative approach, but because some problems and algorithms lend themselves better for recursive implementation, and some others better for iterative implementation. Apart from efficiency, simplicity can be an argument too - recursion can help for very elegant implementations. I'd value elegance or simplicity of source code higher than a close-to-neglectable performance gain or penalty. But in some cases, I'd go for iterative solutions for reasons such as predictable stack use. This when code must run in memory contrained environments (such as small microcontrollers)

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of 'predictable stack use'?

Comment: With recursion, it is hard to say before how much stack will be needed. Iteration makes such a prediction much easier.